# Installed external package (via pip) in Enthought Canopy now import throws ImportError: cannot import name scimath

Tags: python, scipy, enthought

I was trying to use the lmfit package for doing nonlinear least squares fit and I notices that the Canopy curated version is really old and doesn't have most of the objects. So I followed the instructions here https://support.enthought.com/entries/23389761 as I have done before no problem:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install --upgrade lmfit
```

Now when I execute the same exact code some "import" statements (I suppose those involved with scimath) give:

```
ImportError: cannot import name scimath
```

Seems python standard library imports are fine e.g. import os.

I'm on Ubuntu Linux 14 with Canopy 1.5.2

What happened and how can I fix it and avoid breaking it again.

Comment: To be clear, the lmfit package is not in [the Canopy / EPD repository](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/package-index/). Rather, it is in the "Community" (PyPi mirror) repo (marked by the "PyPI" logo in the Package Manager), which contains 11,000 untested ("as is") packages. We do not test for nor necessarily provide dependencies for these packages.

Comment: This makes sense for dependencies. But why is an old version in the package manager if it is coming from PyPI, which has the current version?

Comment: Excellent question: Because it was mirrored from PyPI quite some time ago and not updated since; really vestigial, not a good UX but not a high priority to fix yet.

Comment: @JonathanMarch is there any chance of making it a higher priority? It's quite frustrating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem but I am still not sure why this occurred originally. I went into the package manager and uninstalled scimath reinstalled it and did explicit kernel restarts on my IPython notebooks and interpreters.  This fixed it but I don't see why unless somehow the scimath installation was corrupted. Before that I tried restarting application, computer, and reinstalling canopy.